# Python, MySQL, Django, Syncdb gives DataBaseError (1046, No database selected)

Tags: python, mysql, django, cmd, syncdb

I have installed mysql, added it to services to start automatically, however when i try to run the command line interface it says that it cannot find mysql.exe. It asks me to browse for it. I am using windows 10 64 bit and mysql Cluster 7.4. I am following instructions and all they say to do is just enter the instruction to the command line like this **manage.py syncdb** and that is all that is said on the matter. Thanks in advance for any help that i get.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your database in settings.py 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

where engine is your database engine.

Comment: thank you I hadn't done that but now i don't know what values to supply. That information would also be helpful

Comment: The values you need to supply are as written above,
1. name is your database name
2. user and password are your mysql username password.